# If $f$ is multiplicative then $\sum\limits_{d | n, (N,d) = 1} \mu(d) f(d)$ is multiplicative (Apostol 8.8)

Tags: number-theory

> If $f$ is multiplicative then $\sum\limits_{d | n, (N,d) = 1} \mu(d)  f(d)$ is multiplicative.

In Apostol's book *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, theorem 8.8 I need to show that: $$\sum\limits_{d | a,(N,d) = 1}  \mu(d) \frac{h(d)}{f(d)} = \prod\limits_{p|a,p \;\nmid N} \Big(1-\frac{h(p)}{f(p)}\Big)$$

where $n,k \in \mathbb{N},a = (n,k)$ and $N = k/(n,k)$. The result should follow from theorem 2.18:

> If $f$ is multiplicative we have $\sum\limits_{d | a} \mu(d) f(d) = \prod\limits_{p|a} (1-f(d))$.

However, I'm doing a formal proof of the fact and 2.18 as it is is not sufficient for my needs. In paticular, the first step of the proof in Apostol's book is showing that $g(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} \mu(d) f(d)$ is multiplicative. The formalization of this worked with an indicator function $I(n) = \begin{cases}n = 0 & 0 \\ \text{else} & 1\end{cases}$.

I tried to reproduce this step for my variation with $I(n) = \begin{cases}\text{coprime}(n,N) & 1 \\ \text{else} & 0\end{cases}$. But it turns out that I arrive to the expression $\sum\limits_{d|n,(N,d) = 1} \mu(n/d) f(n/d)$ which is not equal to $\sum\limits_{d|n,(N,d) = 1} \mu(d) f(d)$.

How would you show my theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking too complicated. Your theorem is simply what you get if you instantiate the $f(d)$ in Theorem 2.18 with $f(d) g(d)$, where
$$
g(d) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}\ (d,N) = 1\\
 0 & \text{otherwise .}\end{cases}
$$
This works because $g(d)$ is also a multiplicative function, and the product of two multiplicative functions is again multiplicative.